# Sinatra render and passing rendering options for Redcarpet

Tags: sinatra, markdown, tilt, redcarpet

I’m using Sinatra, and Sinatra uses Tilt for template rendering.

By default Redcarpet has many rendering extensions. How can I use some of these extensions via Sinatra’s `#render` method?

I need to render markdown files with `:gh_codeblock` extension.

Answer (score 2):

In Sinatra, you don’t usually use the `render` method directly, rather you use the [method corresponding to the appropriate template language](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Views%20/%20Templates), in this case [`markdown`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Markdown%20Templates).

You *should* be able to pass any options you want to this method as a hash, and Sinatra (and Tilt) will pass them to the template engine. However, the latest released Tilt gem (1.3.3) doesn’t pass all the options for markdown through, only `:filter_html` and `:smart`, so this won’t work. This is fixed in the current Tilt head, it just hasn’t made its way to a released gem yet.

If you’re using [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/), you could work around this by using [Bundler’s Git support](http://gembundler.com/git.html):

```
gem 'tilt', :git => 'git://github.com/rtomayko/tilt.git'
```

Alternatively you could [download](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt/downloads) the latest version of Tilt and make sure its `lib` directory is on your apps load path, perhaps putting it into a `vendor` directory.

Answer (score 0):

If I read the source code of sinatra, tilt and redcarpet right, you should be able to do something like this:

```
render('your_view', {:gh_codeblock => true}, {HASH_OF_YOUR_LOCAL_VARIABLES})
```

The second parameter to render is an options hash that is passed to the template engine. See:

```
def markdown(template, options={}, locals={})
  render :markdown, template, options, locals
end
```